# Question marks missing in J.P. Donleavy's "Ginger Man"

Tags: punctuation

I am currently reading *Ginger Man*, by J.P. Donleavy, a paperback edition by Abacus (UK). I have noticed that in a lot of sentences that are typically questions, the question mark is missing.

For instance,

> "Would you mind bringing me the bottle to replace the amount splashed in my face."
>   (page 119).

Is this thing common in novels written in English? (Personally, I haven't noticed it elsewhere.) Is it because of the author's style? Or a typo by the publisher?

Comment: Could you add the date it was published?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Originally published in 1955, by Abacus in 1996.

Comment: I'd surmise the writer is conveying that what is normally a question was delivered in a way that it really wasn't.  That character was saying those words in a manner that he or she wasn't asking but telling the other character to bring over a bottle.

Comment: I haven’t read any Donleavy in a very long time but that quote has brought back how unique and distinctive his style was. I can’t think of anyone else who wrote like him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the following [extract](http://naosite.lb.nagasaki-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10069/22045/1/hoken21_2_65.pdf), there are instances where question marks are omitted, especially if the sentence implies a suggestion or a request:

> Sentences that begin with Why don’t you(I, we) or Why not are primarily interrogatives, and they normally take question marks. A large number of these instances are used with question marks, but some of them are not. The instances with question marks can imply suggestions, offers or requests as well as doubt or interrogative meanings.
>
> The expressions similar to Why don’t you or why not include How(What) about, Can I, Can(Could)you, Can’t(Couldn’t)you, Will(Would)you, Won’t(Wouldn’t)you and Will
> (Would)... please.

(naosite.lb.nagasaki-u.ac.jp)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98029/discussion-on-answer-by-user067531-question-marks-missing-in-j-p-donleavys-gi).